# JavaFX console game map object

Tags: user-interface, javafx, roguelike

I want to create little game app with JavaFX like RogueLike game.

My idea is to separate window on 3 parts like:
- details/specifications on the right side (from up to down)
- player console to execute commands, read responds etc. on the bottom
- game map (console style, where colored signs are game elements: items, enemies etc.) from top to player console.

I want to have this parts separated with some .png gap or built in element.

I am wondering what object can give me the possibilities to change its background etc. and iterate through its elements like in 2d array plus it will somehow scale after resizing.

Thanks for advices.

Comment: i think the `AnchorPane` is what you're looking for , but I did not understand the last one (change its background)

Comment: @BoHalim My map is supposed to be console(terminal) like: moving something means to just repaint sign in different place, can change signs color, background (not all the time black) etc.

Comment: Why not use a canvas and draw on it? Keep a state of all objects and just draw where it sees fit. Iterating over Nodes contained in a Pane is not a good solution imo.